# SQLSMO Column Dependencies

Tags: sql-server, smo

I'm trying to help a teammate walk object dependencies in SQL Server. I've had *some* success using things like `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` (and other related DMV/DMFs) but it's falling short due to a lot of weird edge cases (cross database references, inconsistent naming conventions, etc.)

I'm looking into using SqlSMO to walk object dependencies, and so far, it's working pretty well; at least for object dependencies. I give it a procedure name, and use a `DependencyWalker` to tell me things like views, functions and procedures called therein.

But now I need to also know which columns are referenced in the proc. So instead of just knowing my `inputProc` references `someTable`, I'd like to know that it references `someTable.A` and `someTable.B`. So far I haven't been able to find a way to do this using SMO. Anyone know if it can be done?

This is an excerpt of C# code which returns the object references; not sure if and how to modify it to include column-level dependencies as well.

```
public static void Walk()
{
        Server server = new Server(@"localhost\koala");
        Database db = server.Databases["test"];
        Scripter scr = new Scripter(server);
        scr.Options.WithDependencies = true;
        scr.Options.NoViewColumns = false;
        Urn[] urns = new Urn[] { db.StoredProcedures["xdb"].Urn };

        DependencyTree dt = scr.DiscoverDependencies(urns, true);
        DependencyWalker dw = new DependencyWalker(server);
        DependencyCollection dc = dw.WalkDependencies(dt);
        foreach (var item in dc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Urn.Value);
        }
}
```